# Send command to a detached screen with enter?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a screen running a server. That screen is run with:

```
screen -m -d -S server (cmd to start server)
```

Then I want to send a command to the server by doing this:

```
screen -S minecraft -X stuff (cmd)
```

That sends the command to the server but doesn't execute it. (Like if you typed ls in the terminal without pressing enter).

So how can I excecute the command/simulate an enter press?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by forcing a carriage return through.

One way to do that is to append a `control-M` character on the end. A typical way to do that on the shell is to hit `ctrl-v` first, and then press `Return`. The `ctrl-v` tells the shell that the next keypress is to be included literally. That prevents your `Return` from ending the line and issuing the command.

So your command would be something like:

```
screen -S minecraft -X stuff 'ls^M'
```

Where the `^M` part is not literally those characters but in fact the result of pressing `ctrl-v` followed by `Return`.

Comment: OK, that was exactly what I was looking for.
Thought it was something like that.